# removing XML tags using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming SOAP message as given below.  This incoming SOAP message contains an embedded XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) in the `<ns1:disXML>` element:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:process xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
   <ns1:disXML><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TP memberFirstName="Tom"></TP>
</ns1:disXML>
  </ns1:process>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I remove that embedded declaration?

Comment: You cannot - at least not in XSLT. -- BTW, it's not a "tag", it's an XML declaration -  and it's allowed only at the start of an XML document.

Comment: Can't this  xsl will work.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Nothing can work, because the input to an XSL transformation must be a well-formed XML document. -- P.S. Please don't try to post code in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: And a SOAP message *also* must consist of a well-formed XML document, so in fact the premise of the question is flawed: you do not actually have an incoming SOAP message.  You have an invalid request to or response from a SOAP-based web service interface.  Fix it at the sender.

Comment: Hi Michael,thanks for your suggestion. yah i am trying to fix this issue from consumer end. Thanks for your help.